# Spring Data JPA and Hibernate:Exception handling for Database Constraints

Tags: jpa, exception, constraints

Currently I handle `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` by checking the StackTrace for the occurrence of a constraint name defined in a annotation.

Is there any more elegant way to solve the problem?

Spring Validation makes it quite easy as the `ConstraintViolationException`gives me the Property Name and the Message defined in the constraint.

Comment: No. Because what message you get on a constraint violation is database product dependent. What database are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using H2 for testing. Later MySQL or Postgres. But I want to keep it independent from the database implementation. I guess most databases will at least return the name of the violated constraint.

Comment: Yes usually if they have meaningful names. But at the end the implementation is custom anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use Controller Based Exception Handling.
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#controller-based-exception-handling

```
 @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.CONFLICT,
                  reason="Data integrity violation")  // 409
  @ExceptionHandler(DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
  public void conflict() {
    // Nothing to do
  }
```

Comment: I'm actually using Controller Based Excption Handling returning a custom object containing detailed information about the violation (which field, etc). The point of my question is how to best map the database error message to a user-friendly error message.